# iPhone - Catching the end of a grouped animation

Tags: iphone, events, animation, core-animation

I animate 2 views, each one with its CAAnimationGroup that contains 2 CAAnimations. They are launched at the same time (if computing time is negligible), and have the same duration.

How may I do to know when both grouped animation is finished.

I put the `- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag` delegate method, but... What may I test ? Sounds simple, but I don't see the way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two variables to track whether the animations have completed:

```
BOOL firstAnimFinished;
BOOL secondAnimFinished;
```

then in your animationDidStop delegate you check which animation is calling the method and set the flags appropriately. The catch is that you'll need to add a key to identify the animations when they call the delegate (the animations you created will not be the ones calling the delegate, which is a subject for another question/rant). For example:

```
// when you create the animations
[firstAnmim setValue: @"FirstAnim" ForKey: @"Name"];
[secondAnmim setValue: @"SecondAnim" ForKey: @"Name"];

// Your delegate
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation*)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    NSString* name = [theAnimation valueForKey: @"Name"];
    if ([name isEqualToString: @"FirstAnim"]) {
        firstAnimFinished = YES;
    } else if ([name isEqualToString: @"SecondAnim"]) {
        secondAnimFinished = YES;
    }
    if (firstAnimFinished && secondAnimFinished) {
        // ALL DONE...
    }
}
```

Comment: OK but what about CAAnimationGroup ? CAAnimation and CAAnimationGroup does not have any hard property that can be used ???

Comment: and what about the key used in `- (void)addAnimation:(CAAnimation *)anim forKey:(NSString *)key`

Comment: No, CAAnimation/Group does not offer a key that you can use as a unique id for the animations. Unfortunately you have to create your own.

Comment: The key used in addAnimation is not a key in the animation but a key in the layer so you can't use it to determine what animation called animationDidStop (i.e. if I call [addAnimation:anim forKey:@"AnAnimation"], the layer now has a key called @"AnAnimation" but the animation is unchanged.

Comment: So.. No way to name the grouped animation and use that name to know the group has finished to animate ?

Comment: You can name the grouped animation just like a regular animation. In the example above assume that firstAnim and secondAnim are instances of GroupedAnimation